# Converting Mule 1.3 "model" element to Mule 3 equivalent

Tags: mule

I'm upgrading a Mule 1.3 application to Mule 3.2.1 (the latest version).  The Mule 1.3 config file has a "model" element with a number of "mule-descriptor" sub-elements.

```
<model name="theModel">
  <mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="com.company.SomeClass">
    <inbound-router>
      <endpoint address="servlet://service/foo" transformers="ACustomTransformer" responseTransformers="AnotherCustomTransformer" />
      <endpoint address="vm://anEndpoint"/>
    </inbound-router>
    <outbound-router>
      <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.FilteringOutboundRouter">
        <endpoint address="Authenticator">
          <properties>
            <property name="propName" value="propValue" />
          </properties>
        </endpoint>
        <filter expression="/data = null" className="org.mule.routing.filters.xml.JXPathFilter" />
      </router>
      <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.OutboundPassThroughRouter">
        <endpoint address="RequestValidator" />
      </router>
    </outbound-router>
    <properties>
      <property name="someProp" value="someValue" />
    </properties>
  </mule-descriptor>
  <!-- more <mule-descriptor> elements -->
</model>
```

How do I convert this to its Mule 3 equivalent?  Thanks.

---

## **EDIT - 5/29/2012**

**1)** Some mule-descriptors have inbound-routers that point to themselves.

```
<mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="com.company.SomeClass">
  <inbound-router>
    <endpoint address="theName" />
  </inbound-router>
</mule-descriptor>
```

How should these be converted to Mule 3 flows?  When I convert these to flows using the information in your answer, I get an error message on startup, which seems to say that it can't reference the flow because it's still being created (like a circular dependency):

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ref:RequestValidator.20': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'RequestValidator' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'RequestValidator': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.mule.config.spring.factories.InboundEndpointFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'messageSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean '(inner bean)' (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)`

**2)** One mule-descriptor uses the `BridgeComponent` class from the Mule API as its implementation.  How should these be handled?  This class does not exist in Mule 3.

```
<mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="org.mule.components.simple.BridgeComponent">
  <inbound-router>
    <endpoint address="vm://theInboundAddress" />
  </inbound-router>
  <outbound-router>
    <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.FilteringOutboundRouter">
      <endpoint address="vm://theOutboundAddress" />
    </router>
  </outbound-router>
</mule-descriptor>
```

**3)** Another mule-descriptor has a "matchAll" attribute in its `<outbound-router>` element.  How should this be converted to a Mule 3 flow?

```
<mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="com.company.SomeClass">
  <inbound-router>
    <endpoint address="servlet://theInboundEndpoint" />
  </inbound-router>
  <outbound-router matchAll="true">
    <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.OutboundPassThroughRouter">
      <endpoint address="firstOutboundEndpoint" />
    </router>
    <router className="org.mule.routing.outbound.FilteringOutboundRouter" transformer="MyTransformer">
      <endpoint address="vm://secondOutboundEndpoint" />
      <filter pattern="Error*" className="org.mule.routing.filters.WildcardFilter" />
    </router>
  </outbound-router>
</mule-descriptor>
```

**4)** The Mule 1.x config has a handful of `<endpoint-identifier>` elements with names that are identical to the names of some of the `<mule-descriptor>` elements.  These names are also used as endpoint addresses in the `<mule-descriptor>`.  For example:

```
<endpoint-identifiers>
  <endpoint-identifier name="TheEndpointName" value="vm://theEndpointAddress" />
</endpoint-identifiers>

...

<model name="...">
  <mule-descriptor name="TheEndpointName" implementation="...">
    <inbound-router>
      <endpoint address="TheEndpointName" />
    </inbound-router>
    ...
  </mule-descriptor>
  ...
</model>
```

My guess is that the Mule 3 equivalent should look like the code below.  Is this correct?

```
<flow name="TheEndpointName">
  <!--
    My first guess was:
    <inbound-endpoint ref="TheEndpointName" />
  -->
  <vm:inbound-endpoint path="theEndpointAddress" />
  ...
</flow>
```

Thank you again.

## EDIT 5/30/2012

**5)** Some mule-descriptors use the `RestServiceWrapper` class from the Mule API.  When I convert this to a Mule 3 `<flow>`, I get this error:

`The required object/property 'serviceUrl' is null`

I noticed that the mule-descriptor in the Mule 1.x config sets a property called "urlFromMessage", which seems to say that, instead of the URL being provided in the XML config file, it will be provided as a property to the Mule message.  However, the "urlFromMessage" property does not exist in Mule 3's version of the `RestServiceWrapper` class.  Should I be using a different component class in Mule 3?  Since this class is part of the Mule API, is there a standard XML tag that I should use instead?  Thanks.

```
<mule-descriptor name="theName" implementation="org.mule.components.rest.RestServiceWrapper">
  <inbound-router>
    ...
  </inbound-router>
  <properties>
    <property name="urlFromMessage" value="true" />
  </properties>
</mule-descriptor>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `model` has been deprecated.
- `flow` has replaced `mule-descriptor`

And many more, look at your config converted for Mule 3:

```
<flow name="theName">
    <composite-source>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="anEndpoint">
            <transformer ref="ACustomTransformer" />
            <response>
                <transformer ref="AnotherCustomTransformer" />
            </response>
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
        <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/service/foo" />
    </composite-source>
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.company.SomeClass">
            <property key="someProp" value="someValue" />
        </singleton-object>
    </component>
    <outbound-endpoint ref="Authenticator">
        <expression-filter expression="/data = null"
            evaluator="jxpath" />
        <property key="propName" value="propValue" />
    </outbound-endpoint>
    <outbound-endpoint ref="RequestValidator" />
</flow>
```

**NB: This config is valid for Mule 3.2.1 but I can't guarantee it does exactly what you want, you have to test and tweak it!**

More answers:

1) Use a different name for flows and endpoints, they are now registered as individual beans behind the scene and thus can't share the same names. That gives:

```
<flow name="theFlowName">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="theInboundName" />
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.company.SomeClass" />
    </component>
</flow>
```

2) Use the [Bridge pattern](http://www.mulesoft.org/bridge):

```
<pattern:bridge name="theName"
                inboundAddress="vm://theInboundAddress"
                outboundAddress="vm://theOutboundAddress" />
```

3) Use the [`all` routing message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-All) and use `processor-chain` to group several message processors as one:

```
<flow name="theName">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/theInboundEndpoint" />
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="com.company.SomeClass" />
    </component>
    <all>
        <outbound-endpoint ref="firstOutboundEndpoint" />
        <processor-chain>
            <transformer ref="MyTransformer" />
            <wildcard-filter pattern="Error*" />
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="secondOutboundEndpoint" />
        </processor-chain>
    </all>
</flow>
```

4) You can't declare global endpoints in flows and you need to use different names for endpoints and flows, so the actual Mule 3 config equivalent is:

```
<vm:endpoint name="TheEndpointName" path="theEndpointAddress" />

<flow name="TheFlowName">
    <inbound-endpoint ref="TheEndpointName" />
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="..." />
    </component>
</flow>
```

5) Most Mule default components are now available as XML elements, so indeed you need to use:

```
<http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="..." />
```

`urlFromMessage` is gone: instead you can use a [Mule expression](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Expressions+Configuration+Reference#ExpressionsConfigurationReference-EvaluatorReference) to extract the URL from the in-flight message in a dynamic manner. For example, if the URL is provided in an inbound property named `svcURL` use:

```
<http:rest-service-component serviceUrl="#[header:INBOUND:svcURL]" />
```

Comment: Hi David, I'm grateful for all your help.  I'm still working on the mule-descriptors, will have more questions soon undoubtedly...

Comment: Do you mind accepting this one and open new questions as they come during your conversion process? btw good luck with that!

Comment: David I don't want to accept it yet, I haven't tried running my Mule app yet.

Comment: Hi David, I edited the question with some follow-up questions if you have the time.  I didn't create a new question because these questions are still related to converting `<mule-descriptor>` elements.

Comment: Note that from the 1.x config I'm unsure if some endpoints are references to existing ones or declared locally with URL (the distinction was unclear). This is why I use a mix of `ref` and URIs and transport specific endpoints to show you the palette of options. You'll probably have to sort them out and pick the ones that apply to your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I think I was getting `mule-descriptor` names and `endpoint-identifier` names mixed up.  Can you look at question #4 that I just added?

Comment: Thanks David I can't give you the bounty now I have to wait until tomorrow.

Comment: David I know I marked this as answered, but I have another question (see #5) :) :)

Comment: LOL moar questions -> moar answers!

Comment: Nice! That wasn't *too* bad :)

Comment: Yes, now I have to actually try using it though I hope it works